# Why onActivityCreated is called twice when I rotate the phone?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a fragment class that calls a function by Activity class that return an adapter for my custom ListView in fragment, however look like the adapter is returned before that eventList is complete. So my custom listview is not show in fragment.

Tha is my Fragment clas:

```
package newcomer.fragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.fb.newcomersapp.CustomListAdapter;
import com.fb.newcomersapp.Event;
import com.fb.newcomersapp.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FeedFragment extends Fragment{
    private static ListView listView; 
    private static TextView textView;
    EventListListener mCallback;
    private ArrayList<Event> eventList;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;  

public interface EventListListener{

    public String getLocal();
    public CustomListAdapter parseQueryEvents();
    public CustomListAdapter adaptEventList();
    public void openEvent(int position);
    public ArrayList<Event> getEventList();


}



/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Fragment#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.event_list_view);
    adapter = mCallback.parseQueryEvents();
    Log.d("FeedFragment", "Adapter já foi chamado");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCallback.openEvent(position);

        }
    });
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("FeedFragment", "onCreateView");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_header);
    textView.setText(mCallback.getLocal()); 
    return view;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Fragment#onAttach(android.app.Activity)
 */
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (EventListListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement EventListListener");
        }
    }
}
```

Function called:

```
public synchronized CustomListAdapter parseQueryEvents () {
    eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Event");
    query.orderByAscending("startDate") ;
    query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("endDate", new Date()) ;
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseEventList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                ParseObject temp ;
                Iterator<ParseObject> i = parseEventList.iterator() ;
                while(i.hasNext()) {
                    temp = i.next();
                    eventList.add(new Event(temp)) ;
                }

                Log.d("FeedActivity", "Eventos: "+eventList.size());
            } else {
                Log.d("FeedActivity", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    return adaptEventList();
}

public synchronized CustomListAdapter adaptEventList() {
    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, eventList);
    Log.d("FeedActivity", "Adapter Criado");
    return adapter;

}
```

Log:

```
02-05 09:43:17.065: D/FeedFragment(27880): onCreateView
02-05 09:43:17.113: D/Network(27880): Network
02-05 09:43:17.122: D/Network(27880): Network
02-05 09:43:17.772: D/FeedActivity(27880): Adapter Criado
02-05 09:43:17.772: D/FeedFragment(27880): Adapter já foi chamado
02-05 09:43:17.790: I/Choreographer(27880): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-05 09:43:17.832: I/Adreno-EGL(27880): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8610_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1_ release_AU ()
02-05 09:43:17.832: I/Adreno-EGL(27880): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
02-05 09:43:17.832: I/Adreno-EGL(27880): Build Date: 03/07/14 Fri
02-05 09:43:17.832: I/Adreno-EGL(27880): Local Branch: 
02-05 09:43:17.832: I/Adreno-EGL(27880): Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
02-05 09:43:17.832: I/Adreno-EGL(27880): Local Patches: NONE
02-05 09:43:17.832: I/Adreno-EGL(27880): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 + f2fd134 +  NOTHING
02-05 09:43:17.858: D/OpenGLRenderer(27880): Enabling debug mode 0
02-05 09:43:18.377: D/FeedActivity(27880): Eventos: 3
02-05 09:43:37.652: D/FeedFragment(27880): onCreateView
02-05 09:43:37.708: D/Network(27880): Network
02-05 09:43:37.721: D/Network(27880): Network
02-05 09:43:38.398: D/FeedActivity(27880): Adapter Criado
02-05 09:43:38.398: D/FeedFragment(27880): Adapter já foi chamado
02-05 09:43:38.399: D/FeedFragment(27880): onCreateView
02-05 09:43:38.428: D/Network(27880): Network
02-05 09:43:38.431: D/Network(27880): Network
02-05 09:43:39.133: D/FeedActivity(27880): Adapter Criado
02-05 09:43:39.133: D/FeedFragment(27880): Adapter já foi chamado
02-05 09:43:39.146: I/Choreographer(27880): Skipped 95 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-05 09:43:39.190: W/View(27880): requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.ListView{41d65188 IFED.VC. ......ID -360,0-0,442 #7f050041app:id/list_slidermenu} during layout: running second layout pass
02-05 09:43:39.193: D/FeedActivity(27880): Eventos: 3
02-05 09:43:39.559: D/FeedActivity(27880): Eventos: 6
```